# Can't figure out what connector is that. Orcad 9.2

Tags: orcad

I'm trying to reproduce this as I'm learning to use orcad 9.2 but there is that CN1,2,3,4,5 connector I can't find in any of the pre-installed libraries.

Can anyone tell me where can I find it and under what name?

I gave it some thought and I thought it's some pin connector for a power supply. (that is not contained in the circuit board, something like a breadboard type connector?)

Edit: this is the original, it was in a .pdf document and I screenshot the photo. If I had access to it, I would have double-clicked to find out.

I did take into account that it might be a custom component or a test pin and I would waste someone's time by asking, but I want to be sure, I keep searching.

[image: Some circuit I found]

Comment: It can be just *any* connector with at least 5 pins..

Comment: It is a single-pin connector (or rather they are five single-pin connectors).  You may use any single-pin connector, or make one, if you can't find anything suitable in the libraries.  I'd just use a single pad, with a suitable size hole.

Comment: @EugeneSh. actually I'd say that was 5 different connectors since they each have different references. The original may also be a custom component not in the library, sine it is not clear if you are showing us the original or your replica.

Comment: @Trevor_G, Peter Not sure if the op is asking about the *symbol* or the specific connector it is corresponding to in a BOM

Comment: @EugeneSh. yup.

Comment: Double click it, maybe there is a part number inside

Comment: Could be a "test point" part, which might explain the 1 pad per part naming convention.